# Installing Curl for Perl (WWW::Curl::Easy) on Windows

Tags: windows, perl, curl

I am running Strawberry Perl on Windows and need to use WWW::Curl::Easy. 
But "Sorry, no automated install is available on Windows".

There is a README.Win32 on CPAN:

```
Installation on Windows need to be done manually, by editing Makefile.PL.

1. Specify your curl include directory on the line "my @include = qw()".
2. Specify the following parameters on the line below, where <DIR> is your curl directory like this:

my ($cflags,$ldflags,$lflags) = ('-I"<DIR>\\include"', '-L"<DIR>\\lib"','-lcurl -lcurldll');

<DIR> can be for example: "E:\\Perldev\\downloader\\curl-7.18.2-devel-mingw32" (without quotes);
3. Save Makefile.PL.
4. Execute "perl Makefile.PL";
5. Execute "nmake" ( you may need nmake from Mircosoft, which can be downloaded from http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q132084 );
6. Execute "nmake install".
```

Unfortunately, I do not understand how I need to do that. I guess it should be possible with dmake instead of nmake, right? What is meant by the different "include directories"?

Steps taken so far:

- Install strawberry perl
- Download and extract libcurl with ssl(curl-7.40.0-devel-mingw32.zip)
- Download and extract WWW::Curl from CPAN
- edit Makefile.pl

  -#my @includes = qw();
  +my @includes = qw(C:\Strawberry\curl-7.40.0-devel-mingw32\include);
  -#my ($cflags,$lflags, $ldflags) = ('','','');
  +my ($cflags,$ldflags,$lflags) = ('-I"C:\Strawberry\curl-7.40.0-devel-mingw32\include"', '-L"C:\Strawberry\curl-7.40.0-devel-mingw32\lib"','-lcurl -lcurldll');
  ...
  -#replace open(H_IN, "-|", "gcc $curl_h");
  +open(H_IN, "|gcc $curl_h");
- edit curl.xs (work going on)

Can someone please give an example for the installation steps?

Any help is much appreciated ! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

dmake is a port of GNU make, and is not a drop in replacement for Microsoft's nmake, I would use nmake as instructed.

By different include directories I assume your referring to the `$cflags` variable which you include `-I<DIR>\\include` and also the `@include` array where you also include the same path - as instructed by the `README.Win32` file.

Reading the `Makefile.PL`, I can see that the `@include` is actually populated by the `$cflags` variable anyway, as such I see no reason to modify both the `@include` and the `$cflags`, though at the same time there is no harm specifying your path in both places.

Ultimately the `@include` array is searched, the presence of a directory which contains the curl header file `/curl/curl.h` if found, is used to build the perl module.

The instructions given are all that should be needed, please specify your current error, the instructions don't mention editing `curl.xs` what work are you doing on this file?

As an aside, I don't know what your requirements are, but the `LWP::Useragent` module I find is easier to install cross platform, and provides most if not all of the functionality of `WWW:Curl::Easy` and more.

If you are still having problems, please provide details of the errors you are receiving in your question.

Gook Luck.